# Combine parameters from URL with props object in Vue router config

Tags: vue.js, router, vue-router

Here is my router config.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
   {
      path: '/user/:id',
      components: User,
      props: {
        sidebar: true 
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

I can't access to all props (e.g `sidebar` and `id`), only `sidebar` in this config.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 9):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set the prop `sidebar` to `true` (static) and the prop `id` to the `:id` URL parameter (dynamic).

You'll have to use a function which takes the route as a parameter and returns the prop values you want to set on the component:

```js
props: route => ({
  id: route.params.id,
  sidebar: true,
})
```

Have a look at [Function Mode](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html#function-mode) in the vue-router docs for more information.

Comment: Is this still possible if you have multiple components and need to pass different sets of props to different named components?

Answer (score 0):

You can access route path and params like this:

`this.$route.path` or

```
this.$route.params.id
```

from within your function, computed props or your template

Comment: Is there any other way ? From [Vue's doc](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html), it seems to be not the best way to do it.

Comment: Do you want to pass ` props: {
        sidebar: true 
      }` to `User` component?

Comment: i do, i need it in my User component.

Comment: can you check https://jsfiddle.net/ow85z2n8/1/ ? I can get the id in the template