# Using the same view component with different route, but with different props

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I have a view component, ViewDeal, that I want to reuse for different routes `/housedeal/1` and `/cardeal/1`.

I'm using *Vue Router* and it's working nice, except I must know in the view component what route was used.

So this is my component:

```
const ViewDeal = {
  props: ['id'],
  template: '<div>Is this a car deal view or a house deal view? What route was used?</div>'
}
```

And in vue router I have this:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/housedeal/:id', component: ViewDeal, props: true },
    { path: '/cardeal/:id', component: ViewDeal, props: true },
  ]
})
```

I read about [Object mode](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode) in Vue Router which means I can add a prop to housedeal route eg. `{isHousedeal: true}`, but then the `:id` param wont be passed in.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869676/combine-pros-from-url-and-props-object-in-vue-router-config) didn't have any answers to combine url props with object ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work :

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/housedeal/:id', component: ViewDeal, props: {isHousedeal: true} },
    { path: '/cardeal/:id', component: ViewDeal, props: {isHousedeal: false} },
  ]
})
```

Then to retrieve the id, you can use `{{ $route.params.id }}` in your component.

```
const ViewDeal = {
  props: ['isHousedeal'],
  template: '<div>Is this house deal? {{isHousedeal}}. ID : {{$route.params.id}}</div>'
}
```

Comment: Better create named routes and check `this.$route.name` then add additional unnecessary params in `routes.js`